# basename command not working as expected

Tags: bash, shell, unix, ubuntu-12.04, rename

I wrote a shell script to convert a lot of JPGs at my end to pdf

```
 #!/bin/bash
set -xv
for i in `ls -v *.JPG`;
 do i=$(basename "$i")
 convert "$i" "$i.pdf" ;
 done
```

the JPGs are

> DSCN2612.JPG  DSCN2618.JPG  DSCN2624.JPG

and the converted pdfs I get are having names

> DSCN2612.JPG.pdf  DSCN2618.JPG.pdf  DSCN2624.JPG.pdf

Now note the use of basename command in my shell script I expect the resulting name of pdf to be

> DSCN2612.pdf  DSCN2618.pdf  DSCN2624.pdf

Where is the output is different.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and basename --version shows

> basename (GNU coreutils) 8.13 Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later
>   http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html. This is free software: you are
>   free to change and redistribute it. There is NO WARRANTY, to the
>   extent permitted by law.

when on a terminal I just type

> basename DSCN2612.JPG
>   I get the output
>
> DSCN2612.JPG

where as I expect

> DSCN2612

only  so is my understanding wrong or there is some error the way I am using this script.

Comment: You have to specify which suffix you want removed -- for example `basename DSCN2612.JPG .JPG` outputs `DSCN2612`

Comment: you are right I did the same but even then I could not get the converted pdfs I on a terminal typed  
`convert DSCN2602.JPG \`basename $2 .JPG\`.pdf` but the output was bash.pdf

Comment: I added to my answer a different version of your script, see if that is of any help.

Comment: I had an issue since my newlines were CRLF instead of LF so the string had a trailing carriage return.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `basename` command has two uses, stripping path prefixes and (optionally) stripping suffixes.

To strip a path prefix, you can simply pass it a path, for example

```
basename /path/to/file.ext
# file.ext
```

To additionally strip a suffix, you need to tell `basename` the suffix you wish to strip, for example

```
basename /path/to/file.ext .ext
# file

basename DSCN2612.JPG .JPG
# DSCN2612
```

So, `basename` won't "auto-detect" a suffix because in unix, files don't necessarily have suffixes.  In other words, letters after a period aren't necessarily suffixes, so you need to explicitly tell it what suffix to strip.

There are some bash-specific alternatives to "auto-detect" and strip, however.  For example,

```
x="file.ext"
echo ${x%.*}
# file
```

Without knowing more, I might write your script as

```
for jpg in *.JPG; do
    base=${jpg%.*}
    convert "$jpg" "$base.pdf"
done
```

Comment: well to be able to use convert command having a file name extension is
needed what I want is `convert somename.JPG somename.pdf` convert is  a part of imagemagick library in this case I need to necessarily give filename.JPG

Comment: Right, and that is what the script I added at the end should do.

Comment: thats great I just tried my script with your logic base=$(basename "$i" .JPG) that worked

Comment: `${VAR%pattern}` is a POSIX standard feature, not a `bash` extension.